# Does using 16-bit PNG images as a source to ffmpeg result in a more accurate color conversion?

Tags: ffmpeg, images

Suppose I have a sequence of 16-bit PNG images created with a 3D modelling package. I would like to convert the sequence into an MP4 file using ffmpeg.

Does using images with 16 bits per channel result in a more accurate color conversion to YUV as opposed to images with 8 bits per channel? Does ffmpeg directly convert from 16-bit RGB to YUV or does it first convert the images to 8-bit RGB like Gimp 2.8.x does with PNG files?

Comment: I wonder if any open source video encoder implemented 16-bit color depth. AFAIK x264 supports up to 10-bit, and apparently the 8-bit / 10-bit support even needs to be built separately. Not sure about x265.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't look like it.

When I compare, using [SSIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_similarity), a 8-bit YUV stream generated from a 16 bpc RGB input  to a a 8-bit YUV stream generated from a 8 bpc RGB input, the results are identical. That's probably what FFmpeg does internally: `RGB48 -> RGB24 -> YUV 8-bit`.